# to count specific Data in XML file automatically

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I work on XML files everyday, and it requires to check and count any specific tag available in each XML file.

Let suppose there are 100 XML files saved in a folder, currently i am opening each XML file and then find for particular tag to see how many times it appears.

It takes lots of time to open 100 XML files one by one and count any specific tag within it.

IS there anyway i can do it automatically,

I will be very thankful for you

Comment: Please, edit your question and share the code you use. What do you mean by "to open 100 XML? In which application do you open them?

Comment: i have 100 XML files in a folder, i would like to open them using VBA Macro and count the tags and the # of tags count can be in Excel

Comment: i have revised my question

Comment: I asked you **In which application do you open them?**... Do you open them manually and count the tags visually? If not, you should provide the code you use. In this way we will  maybe understand **where to search for the tag(s) you are mentioning**. Otherwise, you should also post the structure of such an eloquent XML file. We need to know in which node(s) to search for and how to set this/these  necessary node(s), too.

Comment: You can search the entire document for tags using [.getElementsByTagName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms765549(v=vs.85)). It returns a collection of all elements with that tag, which will give you the number of occurences in that file. Quick and easy. You could also use XPath to create a query that finds nodes containing the tag, see [SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754523(v=vs.85))

Comment: Both of my suggestions are assuming you are opening the XML as an [XMLDOMDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757878(v=vs.85)) Object. Which I recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't shoot me down for this, but when I read the tags of this question: Excel, VBA, I can only ask: WHY???

I have a bunch of logfiles, containing XML requests and responses, containing a `<Header_Message>` tag, so I have launched following very simple command (with a part of the results):

```
grep -c "<Header_Message>" *.log
2022-01-03.log:531
2022-01-04.log:3345
2022-01-05.log:5101
2022-01-06.log:5770
2022-01-07.log:4165
2022-01-10.log:14639
2022-01-11.log:20824
2022-01-12.log:21409
2022-01-13.log:14
...
```

I looked for a `FindStr` similar command, but I didn't find a way to count using `FindStr`, so you might end up with a Cygwin environment (Windows programs behaving like UNIX commands).

I can't deny you did add the Excel and the VBA tags to this question, so you might want to use the `Shell()` VBA command for launching commandline commands, something like `Shell("grep -c '<Header_Message>' *.log >C:\Temp\outputfile.txt")`, and then you can start analysing the content of `outputfile.txt`.

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru sorry for late reply, i was not feeling well last days.

Comment: I open the XML file in Internet explorer and then finds the tag manually, as you know it automatically shows the # of counts on top of page . E.g. <Day>     or    <Author> i would like to ask if there is anyway where if i run the button of visual basic editor the macro should go to the specific source defined in the code, read and execute all the XML files available in it and search for the specific tag e.g. <Date> or <day> and return the result of each xml in Excel file. i know this question is too much general i am sorry for this